# Connect to MS SQL Server through ODBC

Tags: c++, linux, qt, odbc

I have a Qt 4 application that is trying to connect to an MS SQL Server 2008 database using the Qt ODBC driver. The application runs fine when it is running in Windows; however, the target OS for the application is to have it run in GNU/Linux. When the application runs in GNU/Linux I get the following error:

```
QSqlError(0, "QODBC3: Unable to connect", " [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified")
```

Is there something I need to configure on the SQL server or application side to get the connection to work?

Comment: How did you fixed that? I'm really curious, as I have had the same problem and it appeared, that the mistake was very common ..

Comment: The issue seems to be that you have to create a unixODBC connection on the computer. You cannot just connect directly with the server. The tutorials in the accepted answer explains how that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know much about unixODBC, but have a look here:
unixodbc.org/doc/

For connecting to MSSQL, the following might be useful:
http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html
or .../FreeTDS2.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the `odbc.ini` file in `~/.odbc.ini` . If not working again, try to copy the same file into `/etc/odbc.ini`. If this is not working, as these directories are different for different Unix systems, find all files: `*odbc*\.ini` and see if some of them are empty. If so, replace them with the correct `.ini` file.

I had the same problem and this solved it. But it's a really stupid solution, so I'm looking for a better one. Hope that helped (: